# List weeks in month from Monday to Sunday in Carbon

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I'm trying to get all weeks and week days from a month using PHP's Carbon library. I'd like to compose an array, let's say for current month, to be something like this:

```
array(
    'April' => array(
        array(
            '2017-04-03',  // Monday
            '2017-04-04',  // Tuesday
            '2017-04-05',  // Wednesday
            '2017-04-06',  // Thursday
            '2017-04-07',  // Friday
            '2017-04-08',  // Saturday
            '2017-04-09',  // Sunday
        ),

        array(
            '2017-04-10',  // Monday
            '2017-04-11',  // Tuesday
            '2017-04-12',  // Wednesday
            '2017-04-13',  // Thursday
            '2017-04-14',  // Friday
            '2017-04-15',  // Saturday
            '2017-04-16',  // Sunday
        ),

        array(
            '2017-04-17',  // Monday
            '2017-04-18',  // Tuesday
            '2017-04-19',  // Wednesday
            '2017-04-20',  // Thursday
            '2017-04-21',  // Friday
            '2017-04-22',  // Saturday
            '2017-04-23',  // Sunday
        ),

        array(
            '2017-04-24',  // Monday
            '2017-04-25',  // Tuesday
            '2017-04-26',  // Wednesday
            '2017-04-27',  // Thursday
            '2017-04-28',  // Friday
            '2017-04-29',  // Saturday
            '2017-04-30',  // Sunday
        ),
    ),
);
```

I've tried this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $carbon = new Carbon(new Carbon('2017-04-03'), 'Europe/Sarajevo');
    $model[] = $carbon->addWeeks($i);
}
```

But doesn't suffice my needs since I set a date manually. Of course, I can utilize the power of `strtotime('First Monday of MonthName Year');`, but that as well doesn't help me to figure out a logic to compose an array of weeks and it's days as I've described above.

---

**EDIT:** Basically, what I want is to list all weeks starting from first Monday up to last Sunday in a given month, ie. current, and compose that as an array as I've described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this :

```
$month = "04";
$carbon = new Carbon(new Carbon(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime('2017-' . $month . '-01'))), 'Europe/Sarajevo');
$weeks_array = [];

while (intval($carbon->month) == intval($month)){
    $week_array[$carbon->weekOfMonth][ $carbon->dayOfWeek ] = $carbon->toDateString();
    $carbon->addDay();
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't start from the first Monday of a given month, which for April is on the 3rd.

Comment: To get the first day of a current month, try $firstDayOfMonth = Carbon::now()->setDay(1);